# Way to know what source is reading the most from MySQL Server(RDS)?

Tags: mysql, network-monitoring, optimization, mariadb, bandwidth-measuring

I have a mysql server which is registering very large bandwidth usage. I want to know what options I have for:

1. Knowing what source is using the MySQL server most. (server ip?)
2. What tables or queries contribute most to the bandwidth.
3. Understand if something malicious is happening that I should fix.

I am running on AWS RDS and its using MariaDB.

Comment: Have you tried using `SHOW PROCESSLIST`? See `https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-processlist/`

Comment: Yes, wanted more depth into it.

Comment: One thing I have used for years for troubleshooting and diagnosis is the Percona Toolkit. You may want to give that a look. `https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/index.html`